# NotificationCenter height changes automatically in iOS 11

Tags: ios, notifications, widget, ios11, xcode9

I am facing issue, like once you will click show more button in widget and if you open app and keep background and then go to see the widget then height will changes and will cover the window.

Please check the attached image:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Updated: Height issue has been fixed but I am facing width issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set `preferredContentSize` of your viewController

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.preferredContentSize.width, yourViewSizeHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

I posting my solution to fix the issue:

```
 func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
        guard activeDisplayMode == .expanded else {
            preferredContentSize = maxSize
            return
        }
        guard didLayoutOnce else {

            let oldPreferredContentSize = preferredContentSize
            ***preferredContentSize = maxSize** (To fix issue I removed this line of code)*
            preferredContentSize = oldPreferredContentSize
            return
        }

        let collectionViewSize = phrasesCollectionView.contentSize
        preferredContentSize = maxSize
        if collectionViewSize.height < maxSize.height {
            preferredContentSize = collectionViewSize
        }
    }
```